# Luggage storage at Budapest rail station

Tags: luggage-storage, train-stations, budapest

Are there long term luggage lockers at the Budapest main rail station and if so, what cost?

Answer (score 3):

Note that there are 3 international railway stations in Budapest.  I am presuming that you are referring to the Budapest Keleti station which would generally be referred to as the 'main' station.

There are definitely lockers in Budapest Keleti - I saw (although did not use) them when I was there a few weeks ago.

Based on reports on the Internet it looks like these lockers cost between 400 and 800 forint per day depending on size (US$1-3/day), and can be used for up to 72 hours.

Comment: Keleti, Nyugati and Deli also all used to have a left luggage offices. No idea if they're still there, though.

Comment: 600 Ft. They have been raised to 600 Ft. Keleti is a bad situation, the easy-to-get to locker room is in a really sorry state, homeless people live in the room often. There are lockers on the same level as sales but the elevators are far and often don't work. Kelenföld, well, the entire building is about to collapse, is it a surprise the lockers don't work?